# To understand sudo and "."

Tags: unix, sudo

I am reading [MySQL's manuals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.0/en/mac-os-x-installation.html).

They suggest me that the command

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe          // it seems that sudo = . + master rights
```

is the same as

```
. /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql    // only ., no master rights
```

**Are the two commands same in action?**

Comment: The single dot only signifies your current directory, which is why 'cd' is used with it.

Comment: I have added a question and answer that discusses the use of the dot and the difference between its use for sourcing a file or specifying the current directory. See http://serverfault.com/questions/36052/what-is-the-purpose-of-source-as-a-shell-command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
. /some/path
```

executes [ or includes - which is execution ] a shell script you pointed.

```
./some/path
```

[ notice lack of space after dot ] executes program/script using relative path [ from current directory, not from the top of filesystem ]

sudo executes given command with other [ usually root ] user's privileges.

there is difference between

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
./bin/mysqld_safe
```

and

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
```

the difference is current working directory. for mysql probably that does not meter, but for other/badly written programs that use relative paths - it might meter.

Answer (score 5):

No, those commands are completely different.  You may have a typo in there -- the following two commands *are* equivalent:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
```

And:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
```

Comment: ...except that they are started from a different working directory.

Answer (score 3):

From [Freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/search?q=sudo&submit=Search):

Sudo (su "do") allows a system administrator to delegate authority to give certain users (or groups of users) the ability to run some (or all) commands as root or another user while providing an audit trail of the commands and their arguments.

I'm not sure that you are confused about this, but you might be based on the question.

If you're only confused about why

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
./bin/mysqld_safe
```

Is the same as

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
```

This is because in UNIX, the . means the current directory.  So in this way, you will not search your PATH variable for the nearest mysqld_safe and run it, you will specifically run the one at /usr/local/mysql/bin/.

Comment: I am not sure why you can execute a PATH without "." --- This suggests me that "." or `source` must be in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

In this command:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
```

starts the `mysql` server. As others have said, the period signifies the current directory. It is used in this way to, for example, override the $PATH or to execute a program that's not in $PATH. Remember, in bash, etc., the current directory is not in the $PATH unless you add "." to it (not recommended for security reasons).

Then this command allows you to access `mysql`:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

Note that there's no dot (".") at all in this command.

Comment: mysqld_safe is a valid command.

Comment: @Dennis: Why is there no period in the last command?

Comment: @Masi - because it's absolute path to binary executable.

Comment: I mean to like `. /usr/...`

Comment: I have had an idea that you need to execute commands by `. command`. There is no execution command at the beginning of the last command. Why not?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/36052/what-is-the-purpose-of-source-as-a-shell-command for information about the dot command.